# BarBackgroundColor only changes navbar, not the titlebar

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm just starting out in xamarin forms, right now I'm trying to make it so both the titlebar and navbar for my pages change colour depending on what page you're on. I also have the toolbarposition set to bottom.

The problem is changing the colour only changes the bottom navigation bar, not the top title bar.

My mainpage (the tabbed page) code behind

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#008B8B");
        this.BarTextColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

This changes my navigation bar at the bottom to the colour I want, but leaves the top title bar the default blue colour.

[image: Different colour bars]

Budget & Expenses are two generic content pages (as you can see)

Comment: Is it on android? iOS? Are you using Shell? You should post more background of your problem. Show us if your page have Navigation Title view implemented or not, Is it simple navigation bar?

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Sorry, it's on android, and there's really not much to post since its basically a fresh project but ill update my post with what i can

Comment: Yep, code with screenshots, expected vs actual output would help

Comment: @PatrickGoode there's really nothing else I can post... This is a fresh xamarin forms project, all I've done is what's in the code above, it changes the bottom bar but not the top, theres no other code I can post because there isn't any other code

Comment: Gotcha.  What can you screenshot how it looks?

Comment: @PatrickGoode Updated the main post mate, I've also just realised my title bar also doesn't have an actual title, is that normal when using tabbed pages for navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not set the page title, then correct it would be blank.  To set the color of the title bar at the top for each page, I've used navigation pages for each tabbed page child, then set the background color of those navigation pages

Example:  The xaml for your app's main page

```
 <controls:TabbedPage
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:bla.Controls" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="bla.Views.HomePage"
        >
<controls:TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage BarTextColor="White" Title="Home" Icon="home.png"  Padding="0,-12,0,0">

        <x:Arguments>
            <HomePage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Communities" BarTextColor="White" Icon="people_outline.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <OtherPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</controls:TabbedPage.Children>
```

Your app.xaml:

```
  MainPage = GetMainPage();

  MainPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColorProperty, Color.Green);

  public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
        return new HomePage();  //home page is a tabbed page

     }
```

Comment: Could you explain the code a bit more? Im not sure I understand

Comment: I updated my answer with the little time I have left right now.  Does that help? If so feel free to mark as answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use static resources in your App.xaml for the style of your NavigationPage for all the project solution.

Paste this code in your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Color of Bar Background" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Color of your text on you Bar" />
    </Style>
<Application.Resources>
```

This line is that answers your problem.

```
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Color of your text on you Bar" />
```

I hope it helped you...